# Set a range depends on the cells values and then merge

Tags: excel, vba, range

I have a contiguous cell(s) found on the first row with values `Attach*`.
I need to set a range for this cell(s) and then merge.
the below code may work but it is unreliable at all, because these cases can occur:
1- if only one cell found with value `Attach*` then it will merge it with all cells on the right side (even blank ones),
2- or there are two cells or more with value `Attach*`, but there are un-blank cells on the right side of them.

```
Sub Set_range_depends_on_values()

    Dim ws As Worksheet:  Set ws = ActiveSheet
    
    Dim rngStart As Range
    
    Set rngStart = ws.Rows(1).Find(What:="Attach*", After:=Range("A1"), _
              LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
              SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
              
    If rngStart Is Nothing Then MsgBox "No cells with value Attach*": Exit Sub
              
    Set rngStart = ws.Range(rngStart, rngStart.End(xlToRight))
    
    rngStart.Merge
    
    rngStart.Select   'just to see the result

End Sub
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Not clear, at least for me, how to proceed in case of the second issue. If in the first one all cells starting from the found one up to the last (which should be  not blank?) will be merged, keeping the value of "Attach*" header, how to proceed in the second case? To process the first found one? If so, based on which logic? I mean, what range to be merged and based on what. The last found one? Proceeding as in the first case? If any of the two supposition, which to be the correct approach? Some picture to clarify the problem (before and after) will maybe be necessary, if not clear description.

Comment: "Unreliable" behaviour comes from `xlToRight` and the way Excel manages blank cells. I never rely on `xlToRight` as it can easily mislead you. Use some other method to find out if the cell is empty.

Comment: @FaneDuru , I have added pictures for case 1 & 2

Comment: I must confess that I do not understand too much from the pictures in terms of what is to be done when more occurrences of "Attach*" exist. Also looking to the answer code, **should the code merge all cells between the first and the last one**?

Comment: @FaneDuru , I waited you to post an answer but you did not. As the accepted answer code, I was need to merge all cells between the first and the last one (sure if only one cell found there will not be any merge).

Comment: I was busy and came back to my computer some minutes before. But this is my problem... Yours is the fact that you din not answer my clarification question. **"what range to be merged and based on what"**... Then, what do you understand by **before and after** related to pictures to be placed? Anyhow, I couldn't answer without understanding what is to be done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This added lines will do

```
Sub Set_range_depends_on_values()

    Dim ws As Worksheet:  Set ws = ActiveSheet
    
    Dim rngStart As Range
    
    Set rngStart = ws.Rows(1).Find(What:="Attach*", After:=Range("A1"), _
              LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
              SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
        Set rngStop = ws.Rows(1).Find(What:="Attach*", After:=Range("A1"), _
              LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
              SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
          
    If rngStart Is Nothing Then MsgBox "No cells with value Attach*": Exit Sub
              
    Set rngStart = ws.Range(rngStart, rngStop)
    
    rngStart.Merge
    
    rngStart.Select   'just to see the result

End Sub
```

Comment: I tried and it works perfectly